# Any futuristic chronicle or module for world of darkness?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

I was planning to create a chronicle for Vampire: the Masquerade in which the the Gehenna has ended 300 years ago, the Masquerade is broken and vampires are fighting against a high technology humanity.

It's a post-apocalyptic cyber-punk world with a lot of technology and an open war between vampires and humans.

Does there already exist any module or chronicle based on high technology or future in any of the meta games of world of darkness?

Comment: Hi and welcome to RPG.SE! If you have a moment take the [tour] or visit  [Help Center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help). This question as it stands is a poor fit for StackExchange format. This is not a place that supports freeform discussion or facilitate idea shopping questions. I think it would be better suited to a forum, or you could visit the [chat] and ask folks there.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Sorry for the bad format. I edited the question to make it more precise. I think it now fits it.

Comment: I see good comments here this morning. Especially one commenting about a module. What happen to them?

Comment: it is usually the case that comments trying to answer the question are deleted. An answer should be an answer, not a comment.